# WPF binding in codebehind fails for transformations

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, code-behind

Displaying a rectangle and binding Width, Height, Angle to a view model class works as I expect in XAML

```
<Rectangle 
  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
  Fill="Black" 
  Width="{Binding Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  Height="{Binding Path=Height, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=Angle, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

However, when creating a rectangle in the code-behind I can bind to the Height and Width, but not the Angle.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Binding bindH = new Binding("Height");
  bindH.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

  Binding bindW = new Binding("Width");
  bindW.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

  // DOES NOT WORK
  // AND I DID TRY MANY OTHER COMBINATIONS
  Binding bindA = new Binding("Angle");
  bindA.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

  Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
  SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
  r1.Fill = myBrush;
  r1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5);
  r1.SetBinding(Rectangle.WidthProperty, bindW);
  r1.SetBinding(Rectangle.HeightProperty, bindH);
```

**  // Does not work**

```
  r1.SetBinding(RenderTransformProperty, bindA);

  LayoutPanel.Children.Add(r1);                     // my custom layout panel
}
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: This helped me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5b39636-67c9-47fd-8cb1-bb2f96be5084/binding-the-angle-in-rotatetransform?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Angle property in the ViewModel must be exposed as a RotateTransform. A trivial implementation of the VM would look like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public RotateTransform Angle { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Angle = new RotateTransform(10);
        Height = 50;
        Width = 100;
    }
}
```

The binding then works exactly as you have written it in the Window_Loaded event handler. This makes sense, because in the working XAML version, you specify a RotateTransform object declaratively within the Rectangle's RenderTransform tags.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling RotateTransform's SetValue method with a Binding does not work.  Not sure why.  But going through BindingOperations works.

```
 var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(rotateTransform, RotateTransform.AngleProperty, new Binding("RotationAngle") { Source = myViewModel });
 myControl.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
```

where "RotationAngle" is a double property in your ViewModel.

FYI, Binding from XAML seems to work eventually.  I get a couple of Binding errors at first and then it works...and yes my DataContext is in place well before the object with the RotateTransform is created.  To avoid the Binding errors, I resorted to code-behind and set up the Binding during the Loaded event.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting Angle on Rectangle but you have to set Angle on RotateTransform.

Try this,

```
RotateTransform rot = new RotateTransform();
r1.RenderTransform = rot;
rot.SetBinding(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, bindA);
```

Comment: RotateTransform does not have a method called SetBinding.